# How to combine date and time with a string value in column created by Case in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, datetime, type-conversion, case

I am in the process of creating a query for an SSRS report that will show a column that has DATETIME values.  The column can have `NULL` values.  In my query I would like to use a `CASE` expression.

I want to create this column to just display the date and time value if its not null but if its `NULL` I want it show something like 'No Data'.

The Expression I have is:

```
Case 
  When (Column with Date/Time) is not null then (Column with Date/Time)
  When (Column With Date/Time) is NULL then 'No Data'
End AS Column A
```

However, this query returns an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

I guess because it can't have a string value with a column formatted for Date and time?

Is there any way I can combine these two?  If not I know I can leave it as is and just show the `NULL` value, but I wanted it to look cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

> I guess because it cant have a string value with a column formatted
>   for Date and time?

You are correct. *[CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.* [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) comes into play here.

You'd have to convert your column to a `varchar`.

[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=debeccbcd8b0583145e99209493aec6d)

```
case
   when DateTimeColumn  is null then 'No Data'
   else convert(varchar (20),DateTimeColumn,120)
end
```

You can reference the [`CAST and CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) documentation for other date/time formats.

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly.